# Fade in & out text, stop on the last text

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, text

I have a question about a codepen code i use for my school project.

Can anyone help me?

I have this code and I would like that the loop stop at the last quote ("6th quote"). How can I change the code to do this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">3rd quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">4th quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">5th quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">6th quote</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.quotes {display: none;}
```

**JS**

```
 (function() {

      var quotes = $(".quotes");
      var quoteIndex = -1;

      function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
          .fadeIn(2000)
          .delay(2000)
          .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
      }

      showNextQuote();

    })();
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the current index value within animation complete callback and call function recursively accordingly.

```
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    quotes.eq(++quoteIndex)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000,() => {  if(quoteIndex < 5) showNextQuote(); });
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

```js
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    quotes.eq(++quoteIndex)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, () => {
        if (quoteIndex < 5) showNextQuote();
      });
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

```css
.quotes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">3rd quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">4th quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">5th quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">6th quote</h2>
</div>
```

---

If you want to show the last item at the end then provide the callback after the delay method using [`queue()`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) method.

```
(function () {
  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    quotes
      .eq(++quoteIndex)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .queue(function (next) {
        if (quoteIndex < 5) next();
      })
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();
})();
```

```js
(function() {
  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    quotes
      .eq(++quoteIndex)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .queue(function(next) {
        if (quoteIndex < 5) next();
      })
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();
})();
```

```css
.quotes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">3rd quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">4th quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">5th quote</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">6th quote</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works good! But how can the last quote stay and not disappearing?

Comment: @Jasmin : check second answer

Comment: It won't work :/ I tried it in this codepen: codepen.io/Muhammad_Adil93/pen/xOBzwy
In the end it should be written only "6th quote" without disappearing :/

Comment: @Jasmin : let me test

Comment: @Jasmin : figured the issue and fixed